# Does anyone know if Sound BlasterX AE-5 or AE-5 Plus works on the current Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: sound-blaster

Has anyone tried Creative Sound BlasterX AE-5 or AE-5 Plus on the current Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Support has been added on Kernel 5.5 but I am not sure which is the one (or they both work).

Tried googling online to not much success.

Any users having them to share their experiences here?

Alternatively, are there users with different kernel versions who have success?

Comment: Same problem here. Bought my Creative Sound BlasterX AE-5 Plus in December 2020. Still no sound on Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS on Kernel 5.10.4. Things are evolving and there seem to be people who already have a clue what's wrong. I think we just have to wait a little longer. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/soundblaster-creative-ae-5-plus-no-sound/60516/12

Comment: We do not support hardware related questions, If hardware does not work and it is current please file bug reports.

Comment: Just to add on that, AE-5 works on my configuration.

The Plus model uses the same chip but a different identifier which apparently is patched in kernel 5.14 so might be worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

AE-5 Plus on Fedora latest doesn't work. Different identifier. On windows id = hdaudio\func_01&ven_1102&dev_0011&subsys_11020191. Kernel use Recon3D for it.

I think it would be line with id 0011
in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/sound/pci/hda/patch_ca0132.c?h=v6.3.9#n1314

but i'm in troubles to load patched kernel for check it